# Scope/query based on a specific instance of an has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a `Person` class with many `transaction_records`.

How do I retrieve all the Person which have their last `transaction_record`(based on `created_at`) having a `created_at` attribute older than 14 days.

I'd preferably use ActiveRecord methods (vs long SQL query)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Person.joins(:transaction_records).where('transaction_records.created_at <= ? ', 14.days.ago)
```

Hope It helps !!!